# Nested javascript remote method calls need to work synchronously

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting

I have nested java script remote method calls, the first method gives me an array and I need to iterate through that array and call the second remote method with an array element as an argument and string concatenate the results of the second(the inner one) remote call. Basically I don't want the outer remote method's call back function  to exit before the inner one completes. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have synchronous calls to remote action methods. Salesforce doesn't support it, and the web as a whole forbids it, because it has a detrimental impact on performance. Instead, you'll want to use a callback to the original method:

```
function callout1(data, cb) {
  Controller.method1(data, function(result1, event) {
    // Do any processing you need...
    Controller.method2(result1, function(result2, event) {
      cb(result2);
    });
  });
}
```